# Calling a service using EventListeners

Tags: javascript, typescript, object, dom-events

Disclaimer: Title is not super exact.

I have a service with a public method `openCamera` that calls a library in the global object and attaches eventlisteners to its HTML elements. When I call this service method from the HTML elements events, it works fine, but not when I call it via events attached to the window element. An example below:

```
class ImageService {
  public static AttachEventOnce = false;
  public openCamera() {
    let camera = new JpegCamera('myContainer');
    // captureBtn and videoBox are HTML elements generated from the library once instantiated
    camera.captureBtn.addEventListener('click', () => this.openCamera()); // this works fine
    camera.videoBox.addEventListener('resize', () => this.openCamera()); // doesn't enter here ie not calling it
    if (!ImageService.AttachEventOnce) {
      var that = this;
      window.addEventListener('resize', () => that.openCamera()); // the buttons stop working
      ImageService.AttachEventOnce = true;
    }
  };
}
```

The logic have been somewhat minified but more or less the same. I just want to call the service method again and again when window is resized. I don't care where I attach the listener (HTML element generated from the library or window).

**My take**: The window seem to retain the older object reference too as well as other listeners for other buttons which I think is causing the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The window seem to retain the older object reference too as well as other listerers for other buttons which I think is causing the issue.

Correct — not because it's on `window`, but because you're using an arrow function and only hooking the event once, on the *first* instance where `openCamera` is called. So it doesn't matter whether that instance is discarded by everything else, it's the **only** instance that will receive that `resize` event. (There's also no reason for the `var that = this;` thing and then using `that` inside the function; arrow functions close over `this` like they do variables, so it does exactly what just using `this` within the function would do.)

It's not clear why you're doing that as opposed to hooking the event in an instance-specific way like you are the other events. If you remove the logic hooking it only once, you'll get the per-instance behavior.

Separately: It's odd to be attaching *new* event handlers every time the event occurs. You'll very quickly have them stacking up. The first time (say) you receive a `click`, you'll add a second `click` handler; the next time you receive a `click`, you'll receive two of them (one for each handler), and add two *more* handlers; and so on, doubling every time. This is bad enough with clicks, but disasterous with `resize` as there are a *lot* of `resize` events triggered when the window is being resized.

Comment: Thanks for the response TJ. I however, quite couldn't understand the stacking logic. The click calls the openCamera method again which creates a new camera instance. Shouldn't this somehow destroy the older camera instance object as well as the older eventlistners and recreate new one?

Comment: I tried attaching to the HTML container created by the library but it doesn't seem to listen to resize event unfortunately.

Comment: @Jamie: No, as far as I know `resize` is only fired on `window`. Just hook it for each instance as you do the others. (But...just *once* per instance. :-) )

Comment: sorry for the delay. I was taking some time to digest/understand your information and you are absolutely right. The public static `AttachEventOnce` was causing the issue as passing an anonymous binded function directly inside the debounce solved some of the issue. Thanks for the great insight :)